# merge [xsd] and [xml-schema] tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Noticed there are two tags [xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xsd) and [xml-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-schema) which have identical meanings. XSD stands for XML Schema Definition. XML-Schema means the same thing as XML Schema Definition.

Please merge and make one a synonym of the other.